# TSQL foreach record join a cte and insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I need to create a SQL-Query that uses a recursive CTE to fetch records from TableA. (Tree-Structure). I pass him the "leaf" and want to know the way back to the root.

This works with a @SOME_ID Variable

```
;WITH cte_recursive AS 
        ( 
            SELECT ID, SUB_ID FROM tableA 
            WHERE SUB_ID = @SOME_ID
            UNION ALL
                SELECT parent.ID, parent.SUB_ID
                FROM tableA parent
                INNER JOIN cte_recursive child ON child.ID = parent.SUB_ID
        )
```

What I need to acchieve now is, that I take every record from TableB
and use tableB.SOME_ID for the CTE Expression and create an insert into TableC foreach record the CTE generates plus some fields from TableB

(cte_recursive.CHILD_ID, tableB.SomeValue, tableB.SomeOtherValue)

So my question here is, how do I pass the tableB.SOME_ID to the cte expression ?

So in TableA I got something like this:

ID, SUB_ID

1 ,   2

2 ,   3

2 ,   4

2 ,   5

5 ,   6

7 ,   8

8 ,   9

If I pass him SUB_ID = 5, the CTE returns me the Records #1, #2, #3, #4, #5
as SUB_ID = 5 is a Child of  a Child of a child... of ID = 1

Comment: Just `JOIN` tableB in both `SELECT`statements.

Comment: I cant, since in the UNION part, there is no TableB Entry for either parent.ID nor parent.Sub_ID. Since the cte creates n records for 1 tableA record. Ill expand my opening post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create table valued function

```
create function ftBranchOf
(
    @SOME_ID int -- actual type of @SOME_ID
)
returns table as return
(
    WITH cte_recursive AS 
    ( 
        SELECT ID, SUB_ID FROM tableA 
        WHERE SUB_ID = @SOME_ID
        UNION ALL
            SELECT parent.ID, parent.SUB_ID
            FROM tableA parent
            INNER JOIN cte_recursive child ON child.ID = parent.SUB_ID
    )
    select * from cte_recursive
)
```

And then use it in your query

```
insert into TableC (...)
select p.ID, b.SomeValue, b.SomeOtherValue
from TableB b
    cross apply ftBranchOf(b.SOME_ID) p
```

Comment: Havent thought of that, works like a charm. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx Found this when searching for the CROSS APPLY on some Syntaxproblems

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you want, so just guessing

```
;WITH cte_tableB AS
(
    SELECT * FROM tableB
)
, cte_recursive AS 
( 
    SELECT ID, SUB_ID, SOME_ID FROM tableA 
    WHERE SUB_ID IN (SELECT SOME_ID FROM cte_tableB)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT parent.ID, parent.SUB_ID, SOME_ID 
        FROM tableA parent
        INNER JOIN cte_recursive child ON child.ID = parent.SUB_ID
) 
INSERT [YourTable] ([YourColumns...])
SELECT [YourColumns...]
FROM cte_recursive
INNER JOIN cte_tableB ON cte_recursive.SomeID = cte_tableB.SomeID
```